# What is the closest font to Helvetica available on Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts

As I understand we don't have the font Helvetica in Ubuntu. Is there any font that is very similar to it? How can I install it?

Comment: is this helpful? http://askubuntu.com/questions/445586/missing-adobe-helvetica-bold-fonts

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many [Alternative Typefaces to Helvetica](https://www.lifewire.com/what-fonts-look-like-helvetica-1077403). Download one and install. For example, [Coolvetica](https://www.dafont.com/coolvetica.font).

After downloading a .zip archive, extract it with an archive manager. You may then install fonts using the method [Helio describes](https://askubuntu.com/a/599944/567307).

Answer (score 33):

The PostScript language defines 35 core fonts in PostScript 2. Among them is the **Helvetica** family. A properly configured system should automatically substitute one of the following fonts, if available:

- Microsoft commissioned a copy of Helvetica – The well-known **Arial**. (`ttf-mscorefonts-installer`)
- Google commissioned the Croscore fonts, designed to be metrically compatible with Microsoft fonts. The Arial equivalent is **Arimo**. (`fonts-croscore`)
- Red Hat commissioned a set of fonts designed to be metrically compatible with Microsoft fonts. The equivalent of Arial is **Liberation Sans**. (`fonts-liberation2`)
- URW released open-source clones of the 35 Postscript fonts for ghostscript. The Helvetica equivalent is **Nimbus Sans**. The metrics are slightly different from Arial.
- GUST TeX Gyre is based on the URW fonts. The Helvetica equivalent is **TeX Gyre Heros**. The metrics appear to have been adjusted to match Arial. (`fonts-texgyre`)
- GNU FreeFont is based on the URW fonts, with the same metrics. The Helvetica equivalent is **FreeSans**. (`fonts-freefont-ttf`)

**Reference**

- ArchWiki: [Metric-compatible fonts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Metric-compatible_fonts)

---

[image: font samples]

Answer (score 5):

I use Arial:

[image]

See [Install MS Truetype Fonts system-wide for all users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55643/install-ms-truetype-fonts-system-wide-for-all-users) for how to install it.

Answer (score -3):

Try the font 'Phetsarath OT' (at least it shows up in Inkscape; not sure if it is a system-wide font).

LaTeX on Ubuntu advertises having Helvetica as an option, but they actually use the one I mentioned.

Comment: Phetsarath appears to be a font for the Lao language. Latin characters are likely pulled from the system fallback font.